Cordyline stunted growth from crown
I have 2 australis red star cordylines (about 4ft tall) which have done very well for the past 3 years, having been over-wintered in the garage on polystyrene bases.  I have just noticed that the larger one has stunted growth in the centre.  The new leaves which emerge from the crown have gone brown and crispy at the very tips (about 1 inch) and twisted together preventing the leaves from growing and opening out naturally. Any advice please on how to save it and prevent future occurrences?
Thanks,
Mel

My best bet would be to remove the crispy tops holding them together - I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with it,  so this will let it survive, even if it looks a bit so-so for a couple of months
